# Given a range of numbers, show label instead of axis value?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

So I have this interesting use-case I need to fulfill at work and I'm kind of at a loss at the moment.

What I need to achieve is this: I have a Google Chart scatter plot with a bunch of X/Y points. The X and Y are determined by numbers so naturally the X and Y axis legends shows numbers in a variety of ranges.

However, instead of showing the numbers, I need to show labels.

So if I have a range of numbers that are say, 209009 - 219959, then instead of showing 200,000 and 210,000 on the X-axis I need to show "MyLabel".

I cannot currently find any way of doing this and was wondering if it's even possible to do, using built-in Google Chart functions?

Comment: can you add a snipet of the code you're using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `ticks` option, which takes an array of values or objects.
using object notation, you can provide the value (`v:`),
and the formatted value (`f:`).

```
hAxis: {
  ticks: [
    {v: 201000, f: 'My Label A'},
    {v: 202000, f: 'My Label B'},
    {v: 203000, f: 'My Label C'},
    {v: 204000, f: 'My Label D'},
  ]
},
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_scatter'));

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y0'],
    [201000, 54000],
    [202000, 55000],
    [203000, 56000],
    [204000, 57000]
  ]);

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      bottom: 48,
      height: '100%',
      left: 64,
      right: 48,
      top: 48,
      width: '100%'
    },
    hAxis: {
      ticks: [
        {v: 201000, f: 'My Label A'},
        {v: 202000, f: 'My Label B'},
        {v: 203000, f: 'My Label C'},
        {v: 204000, f: 'My Label D'},
      ]
    },
    height: '100%',
    legend: {
      position: 'top'
    },
    width: '100%'
  };

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.chart {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="chart" id="chart_scatter"></div>
```